# Reading from the same document multiple times in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

If I had a function that reads the same document from Firestore multiple times does each read count towards the read count?

Or does the SDK use the cached version and so only add a single count?

I forgot to add. This is a question about the Admin SDK in a cloud function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to realize is that you're charged for every document that is read for you on (and usually downloaded from) the server. So if a document is read from the cache, that usually won't count as a charged document read. But if the client needs to check with the server whether its local copy is up to date (the average document-level `get()` call), that does lead to a document read charge.

The Admin SDKs don't have a persistent cache, so in general each read would have to reach out to the server - and thus count as a charged document read. But some of it depends on how you actually perform the read operation, so it'll be easier to help if you can show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.

Comment: Ah, ok, this makes sense and answers my question. Thanks